# How to get closest parent of element in Playwright?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, playwright

I am quite new in playwright and i cannot find solution for how to get parent of element?
Here is what i have so far:

```
    const deliveryItems = await page.locator('.js-delivery-container'); //Items
    const deliveryMethod = deliveryItems.locator('input[value="50"]'); //input in items selected by value
    const example_parent = await deliveryMethod.closest('.js-delivery-name'); //name what i want to check
    await expect(example_parent).toHaveText('Osobní odběr'); //check if selected right delivery
```

But when i run it.. there is a Error what popup in console:

```
 TypeError: deliveryMethod.closest is not a function

  33 |
  34 |         const deliveryMethod = deliveryItems.locator('input[value="50"]');
> 35 |         const example_parent = await deliveryMethod.closest('.js-delivery-name');
```

Can anyone explain me this? Thanks

My structure looks like this:

```
<div class="select-content-box js-delivery-container">
   <div class="select-content delivery-icon-factory">
        <div class="extended-title transport-icon js-delivery-name">Osobní odběr</div>
        <div class="extended-price js-delivery-price"></div>
        <div class="select-btn">
            <label class="label toggle">
                <input type="radio" name="radio-delivery" value="50">
                <div class="toggle-control"></div>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="cleaner"></div>
        <div class="select-address" style=""></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know to use xpath for parent element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ElementHandle.closest()` method you are trying does not exist in the API at the moment (or is not yet available in the Playwright version you use, I only found it in this discussion [#6015](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/6015)). That's the reason for the error.

### The problem

You want to find a connection between the input field based on its value (`input[value="50"]`) and the `.js-delivery-name` element which is not possible, or at least any `.parentElement?.parentElement?.nextSibling?.nextSibling...` structure would be extremely fragile, same applies to [XPath axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes) (they are not even in *child-ancestor* relation here but a kinda *"second niece/nephew-second aunt/uncle"* relation).

### Possible solution

I suggest the following. "Playwright can [select elements based on the page layout](https://playwright.dev/docs/selectors#selecting-elements-based-on-layout). These can be combined with regular CSS for better results."

1-2.) **`desired name within + delivery items:`** using the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Combinators#child_combinator) and [universal selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors) you can compose patterns that can grab your desired elements within a container element, e.g.: `.js-delivery-container > * .js-delivery-name`

3.) **`above this input:`** when you have the exact selector then you can grab it by finding the closest element matches another CSS selector query **in specific directions** with `:above()`, `:below()`, `:near()`, `:left-of()` and `:right-of()` methods, e.g. `:above(input[value="50"])`. As the docs says: "Matches elements that are above any of the elements matching the inner selector".

```js
//                                delivery items       desired name within    above this input     
//                           ______________________  __  _______________  ________________________
//                          |                      ||  ||               ||                        |
const parent = page.locator('.js-delivery-container > * .js-delivery-name:above(input[value="50"])')
await expect(parent).toHaveText(/Osobní odběr/)
```

*Note:* Layout selectors use [bounding client rect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to compute the distance and relative position of the elements, so these `above`, `below` etc. directions are strictly meant for layout position and not for DOM ancestry.